# Neural Machine Translation with multi-language input to a single-language output?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, large-language-models, machine-translation

I'm looking for NMT paradigms where the input to the model is the same text in N languages (e.g., L1, L2, L3) and the output is the translation in a different target language (e.g., L4).

However, I have the Rosetta Stone problem. Each input text might be randomly noisy/incomplete, that's why I think such a paradigm might help. The hope is to train a model that can compensate for the noise (missing elements) in one input text using the parallel elements in the other input texts (assuming that no element is missing from all input texts).

For training, I have parallel L1-L2-L3-L4 text quadruplets. I also have texts in each individual language separately that I can use for pre-training. Are there any methods to pre-train NMT models using single-language data?